# WinMerge add diff. instead of overwrite

Tags: winmerge

When using WinMerge I press Alt + Left to overwrite the different code on the left with the code on the right.
Is there any way likewise to add the diff. code on the right either above or below the code on the left?

Or alternatively is it possible to change the red highlighting instead, so you can select what is overwritten, and what gets transferred?

Answer (score 0):

While not as convenient, you should be able to just click into the text and start typing (and also using shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Once you're done with some edit (or part of it), hit refresh to update the highlighting. You don't have to save any changes till you're done with the file.

I don't think there's any convenient way to pick both versions one after the other.

Comment: At the moment I'm copy/pasting and using auto refresh. The above question was to alleviate all the back and forth.

Comment: Already thought so, but guess you're out of luck for now, unless I'm missing some feature as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to transfer text, is to select it in one file with the mouse,
then drag and drop it to its place in the other file.

Note that to copy the text, you must press on <kbd>Control</kbd>,
as the default is to move the text, rather than copy.